# Angular JS Touch Slider displaying NaN error when used with Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, nouislider

I'm trying to use the Angular JS range slider with my ionic app but it displays as below:

[range slider error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxMCC.png)

I've installed npm angularjs-slider but there is an error in the console - Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined. Can anyone help. app.js Code below followed by index.html code. Thanks

```js
  angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ngAutocomplete', 'rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap'])

  .controller("MainCtrl", function() {
    console.log("Main Controller says: Hello World");
  })

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

      .state('main', {
      url: "/main",
      templateUrl: "templates/main.html",
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })

    .state('page', {
      url: "/page",
      templateUrl: "templates/page.html",
    })

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
  });

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $modal) {
    //Range slider config
    $scope.minRangeSlider = {
      minValue: 10,
      maxValue: 90,
      options: {
        floor: 0,
        ceil: 100,
        step: 1
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/rzslider.css">

  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  <!-- cordova script -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <script src="ngautocomplete.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
  <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script src="js/rzslider.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- your app's js -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ionicApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" disable-tap>
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

And I link it to my page template by:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article>
    <rzslider rz-slider-model="rangeSlider.minValue" rz-slider-high="rangeSlider.maxValue" rz-slider-options="rangeSlider.options"></rzslider>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Having the same issue on my project but only when I am on Chrome (desktop version, but in Mobile mode : CTRL+SHIFT+I and CTRL+SHIFT+M) or on Chrome Mobile (iOS and Android) ...  Any news ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use jQuery 3.0.0, there is an incompatibility, try with jQuery 2.2.4

I open an issue on github :
https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider/issues/365

Try the new version 5.1.1, it could fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Oziris this was the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Because you had referenced wrong scope variable, it should be `minRangeSlider` instead of `rangeSlider`

**Markup**

```
<rzslider 
   rz-slider-model="minRangeSlider.minValue" 
   rz-slider-high="minRangeSlider.maxValue" 
   rz-slider-options="minRangeSlider.options">
</rzslider>
```

**Edit**

Remove `angular.js` cdn reference as you are already loading `angular` files from `ionic-bundle.js`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but the slider is still broken... :(

Comment: Again, thanks for the suggestion but sill not working, arrangement below:
'<!-- range slider -->  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/rzslider.js"></script>
      
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>'

Comment: WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
app.js:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined